# How to create a generic page in PHP

Tags: php, e-commerce

this is my first post on here and I have searched for this question and have been unable to find an answer, I don't know if it's because I have missed it or because there isn't one, but basically...

I'm creating an e-commerce website using PHP and MySQL. I would like to create a page called 'generic.php', and when the user clicks on a game it always takes the details of that game and shows it on the 'generic.php' page. How would I go about doing this?

My initial thought was to create an SQL statement so that when the user clicks on the game it posts the details from the database to the page.

I'm not new to PHP, so I will probably understand a lot of what is said. Any help would be great! 
Thank you :)

Comment: Its because such questions do not get fit into the SO format and so get closed... Do read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on the top right to get an idea. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I'd suggest starting reading a book/site/whatever on how websites work. While we're happy to help, teaching you the basics is not what the site is about. If you have some code, we'll try to help fix that.

Comment: I see, okay thank you both for the replies... I'll find a book to read :)

Comment: @DanielMorgan: All the best and see you around!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go two routes.

1. You can post the gameID [like the post method from a form] you want the "Generic.php" to load and show, and get the page to retrieve that and use it in the SQL statement.

**Example:** I posted the variable gameID to Generic.php so I would get this back using $_POST["gameID"]

1. The other route is just to put the gameID in the URL.

**Example:** I navigated to Generic.php?gameID=Halol - I would get the URL variable by using $_GET["gameID"]

~Hope this helps~

Comment: Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense. I think the second route would be better, as I think that POST methods should mainly be used for updating, inserting and deleting data from a database, thank you very much! Has helped